# error TS7028: unused label

Tags: angular

In angular4 i get below error. Kindly solve anyone. Thanks in advance.

**new-cmp-component.ts:**:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core'; // here angular/core is imported .

@Component({
  selector: 'app-new-cmp',
  templateUrl: './new-cmp.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./new-cmp.component.css']
})
export class NewCmpComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() {
       newcomponent: 'Entered in new component created';
  }
  ngOnInit() {    
  }

}
```

**Error:**
ERROR: in src/app/new-cmp/new-cmp.component.ts<11,8>: error TS7028: unused label.

Comment: newcomponent: 'Entered in new component created'; remove this line from constructor and check

Comment: Try and declare the newcomponent outside the constructor and then within constructor this.newcomponent = 'Entered in new component created'.

Answer (score 2):

My guess is that you are using TSLint. The error occurs because you declared a variable (without using `const` or `let` or `var` before it), and never use it. It is also declared in the wrong way. It should not be `newcomponent: 'Entered in new component created'`, but rather (If it is a constant) declare it as

```
const newcomponent = 'Entered in new component created';
```

Note that you are using colon (:) instead of equals (=) when declaring it. If you use colon, you should specify a type (e.g. `const myLabel:string;`)

Answer (score 1):

You should first declare the variable, then use it.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core'; // here angular/core is imported .

@Component({
    selector: 'app-new-cmp',
    templateUrl: './new-cmp.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./new-cmp.component.css']
})
export class NewCmpComponent implements OnInit {

    const newcomponent = 'Entered in new component created';

    public newcomponent2: string;

    constructor() {
        this.newcomponent2 = 'Entered in new component created';
    }
    ngOnInit() {    
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Now, I declare the variable "newcomponent" out side of constructor method.
This is working fine now.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core'; // here angular/core is imported .

@Component({
  selector: 'app-new-cmp',
  templateUrl: './new-cmp.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./new-cmp.component.css']
})

export class NewCmpComponent implements OnInit {

  **newcomponent: 'Entered in new component created';**

  constructor() {       
  }
  ngOnInit() {    
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was having same error at declaration line:

```
declarations:[AddFlightPage]
```

I just declared it with let and it worked.

```
let declarations:[AddFlightPage]
```